# how can i use html file input feature to just retrieve the fullpath of file without having it upload into system via php?

Tags: php, html

i've a html form to let user choose file via GUI, the purpose actually just to retrieve the fullpath of file choose upon form submitted. But php itself will first upload the file into system once form is clicked on submit. Is there a way to have the GUI to choose file but skipping the upload as my purpose is just to retrieve the file path.

Comment: We need to see what you have done to know how we can answer your question.

Comment: You mean you want just the filename of one of these `<input type="file" name="somefile">` in a form?

Answer (score 1):

To a certain degree yes this is possible, but you won't be able to get the full path name due to browser sandboxing. On chrome paths appear as `C:\fakepath\filename.ext`.

The following is a small example of how to get the pathname in JavaScript when a file is selected:

```js
document.getElementById("fileselect").addEventListener("change",function(event){
  console.log("value",this.value); // shows C:\fakepath\filename.ext
  for(var a=0; a<this.files.length; a++){
    console.log("file",a,this.files[a].name); // shows filename.ext
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileselect" />
```

For more information on what you can do with files on the client side, read [File API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673542(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: this is not what i want, as it will run the process of uploading file too. it seem like due to security concern, there isn't a way to get full path retrieve. And this the only way which is "select file-> system uploading -> get 'fake' path". :(

Comment: at no point does this upload the file to the server